# Searching through database with python

Tags: python, mysql, bioinformatics

My question deals with python I'm searching through a data base and I want to query mysql for this:
Species Common_name, genus and species of with the sequence start with “MDPSSID”.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Hi generally it is considered good practice to actually show us some effort first :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="user",
                      passwd="password", 
                      db="database") 
cur = db.cursor() 
cur.execute("SELECT common_name , genus , species  FROM table WHERE sequence LIKE 'MDPSSID%'")
```

Comment: This works but we also have to join some tables because the species table does not have all the sequences in it.  I was looking for the LIKE Command though.  Thank you